# Ruby on Rails Engines: When/Why in layman's terms.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-engines

I have been reading some tutorials on Rails engines from the official documentation and third party tutorials and I'm not exactly sure if I understand the uses of engines. I was wondering if someone could explain when and why you would use an engine instead of working in the main /app directory.

Just to expand a bit on what my understanding so far is:

Engines are like mini applications that live in the /lib directory of your application. The engines can share models at the top level or have their own.

Engines are useful for logically grouping components of your application (for example an Admin engine, Blog engine, etc) which I could see being useful in splitting up the work between developers without conflicts.

The example I keep seeing is creating an Admin engine that has it's own User model and it's own specific views. Would a regular user also have it's own engine? Would they share the same table in the database? These are the types of questions that sort of confuse me.

If anyone can help me out a bit, it would help a lot before I get started on my own application. I would hate to create my application with poor design and have to go back and completely re-do it. Thanks!

Comment: Great write-up here: http://tech.taskrabbit.com/blog/2014/02/11/rails-4-engines/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+hacker-news-feed-50+(Hacker+News+50)

Answer (score 3):

Engines are great for creating self-contained modules that can be tested independent of your larger application. Normally these are used to create components that can be re-used between different applications, although there are some occasions where you will want to carve up a large application into smaller, more compartmentalized engines.

I'd suggest using them only when you want to make a part of your application re-usable. Once you start carving up your application into engines you might find you're making your life unnecessarily difficult. There's no specific gain between a monolithic application, and one composed of several modules.

The only exception to this would be if you have a large, distributed team and each team needs to be able to work somewhat independently. The overhead of the engine approach is worth paying for in this case. Normally it isn't.